# Create interactive GTK interface through Lua

Tags: lua, gtk

I'm building an application heavily reliant on plugins. These are coded in Lua for easier and faster development.

I now want to add GTK user interfaces for the plugin's configurations. The problem right now is that I need a way to interact with the interface through external code (signals and callbacks basically). And I'm not sure how to implement that behaviour with only an external Lua script.

Is my approach correct or should I instead implement a native solution in my framework for UI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on linux or BSD, Lua is a perfectly valid choice for GTK. Just take a look to the [lua-lgi project](https://github.com/pavouk/lgi). Once installed, you can start building an UI in a matter of seconds:

```lua
lgi = require'lgi'
Gtk = lgi.require'Gtk'
dialog = Gtk.MessageDialog { text = 'This is a text message.', buttons = 'CLOSE' }
dialog:show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

The greatest feature of `lgi` is that it works for every GObject based library, e.g. [`cairo`](https://www.cairographics.org/), [`goffice`](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/goffice), [`gnome-db`](http://www.gnome-db.org/) and many more.

If you are on Windows you are out of luck. I have built a [working installer](https://github.com/pavouk/lgi/issues/98) but it is more a proof-of-concept than a real project. The road to that has been really tough, expecially because [gobject-introspection](https://gi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (widely used by `lgi`) is not cross-platform friendly yet.

I have no experience on other OS.

Comment: I've looked on that too, but my problem is not about building an UI on Lua, it's about retrieving an already loaded UI element to be able to modify it with a script. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: `lua-lgi` provides the same API you have in C: you are able to do whatever you can do with plain GTK. From what I understood from your request, you can easily get widgets from a `GtkBuilder` (i.e. from the XML file generated by glade) and edit them in any way possible.

Comment: If that's the case then it's probably the best way to achieve my goal. The only problem is the cross-platform issue, but I'll have to look for solutions later. Thanks for the help!